# php array manipulation - manipulate a certain set and map it back to the array

Tags: php, arrays

i'm pulling data from the database and get an array of the format:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["topicname"]=>
    string(19) "Signs giving orders"
    ["title"]=>
    array(4) {
      [0]=>
      string(4) "Stop"
      [1]=>
      string(8) "No entry"
      [2]=>
      string(10) "No cycling"
      [3]=>
      string(17) "No motor vehicles"
    }
    ["filename"]=>
    array(4) {
      [0]=>
      string(44) "DQP0GVcUA2dG8ZfqeVYLO68YodgYnJMOjJw2o2iC.png"
      [1]=>
      string(44) "vWUcHGX3VVKPT08JXh9mAqZ40pT0vfDJ78Yoqovz.png"
      [2]=>
      string(44) "bplX8bbwHzHKX9n6SvvQiYNhkWwKxi2bhsrQ94U2.png"
      [3]=>
      string(44) "8KAEovxQn3EgzHoZg1euSgNYTFupnLdKusJ4SIEP.png"
    }
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    ["topicname"]=>
    string(13) "Warning Signs"
    ["title"]=>
    array(4) {
      [0]=>
      string(29) "Road narrows ahead both sides"
      [1]=>
      string(47) "Road narrows on right (left if symbol reversed)"
      [2]=>
      string(10) "Crossroads"
      [3]=>
      string(22) "Junction on bend ahead"
    }
    ["filename"]=>
    array(4) {
      [0]=>
      string(44) "uZ7fnDjlYfKU3pdSQ7wAq4siFryA6jSEitmRyPhp.png"
      [1]=>
      string(44) "4pslo6cC0I2E606DscWxiDD3sCBW7ZGaESQES4r0.png"
      [2]=>
      string(44) "xdVBMpV6PTLtX48M67kfWOqy59rsYMDZMuWbqDwl.png"
      [3]=>
      string(44) "hLtIGikARgARqmSqit4mqNXRFJthipH6O5vqxlbN.png"
    }
  }
}
```

The above array is generated by the bit below:

```
$data = array();

foreach ($content as $value)
{
      $title = explode(',', $value->title);
      $filename = explode(',', $value->filename);
      $d = array();

       $d['topicname'] = $value->topicname;
       $d['title'] = $title;
       $d['filename'] = $filename;

        $data[] = $d;

}
var_dump($data);
```

From here, my goal is to get the `["filename"]` and manipulate it then return it to the array set so that at the end, i get an array of the structure:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["topicname"]=>
    string(19) "Signs giving orders"
    ["title"]=>
    array(4) {
      [0]=>
      string(4) "Stop"
      [1]=>
      string(8) "No entry"
      [2]=>
      string(10) "No cycling"
      [3]=>
      string(17) "No motor vehicles"
    }
    ["filename"]=>
    array(4) {
      [0]=>
      string(44) "/storage/images/DQP0GVcUA2dG8ZfqeVYLO68YodgYnJMOjJw2o2iC.png"
      [1]=>
      string(44) "/storage/images/vWUcHGX3VVKPT08JXh9mAqZ40pT0vfDJ78Yoqovz.png"
      [2]=>
      string(44) "/storage/images/bplX8bbwHzHKX9n6SvvQiYNhkWwKxi2bhsrQ94U2.png"
      [3]=>
      string(44) "/storage/images/8KAEovxQn3EgzHoZg1euSgNYTFupnLdKusJ4SIEP.png"
    }
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    ["topicname"]=>
    string(13) "Warning Signs"
    ["title"]=>
    array(4) {
      [0]=>
      string(29) "Road narrows ahead both sides"
      [1]=>
      string(47) "Road narrows on right (left if symbol reversed)"
      [2]=>
      string(10) "Crossroads"
      [3]=>
      string(22) "Junction on bend ahead"
    }
    ["filename"]=>
    array(4) {
      [0]=>
      string(44) "/storage/images/uZ7fnDjlYfKU3pdSQ7wAq4siFryA6jSEitmRyPhp.png"
      [1]=>
      string(44) "/storage/images/4pslo6cC0I2E606DscWxiDD3sCBW7ZGaESQES4r0.png"
      [2]=>
      string(44) "/storage/images/xdVBMpV6PTLtX48M67kfWOqy59rsYMDZMuWbqDwl.png"
      [3]=>
      string(44) "/storage/images/hLtIGikARgARqmSqit4mqNXRFJthipH6O5vqxlbN.png"
    }
  }
}
```

notice how now the filenames have been modified. to achieve the above, i get the array returned from `var_dump($data);`, then do my manipulation as follows:

```
foreach ($data as $val)
{
     foreach ($val['filename'] as $filecheck )
     {

          //get extension since images and videos are in separate folders
          $file_ext = File::extension($filecheck);
          $images = array('jpg','gif','png');
          $videos = array('mp4', 'webm', 'ogg');

          if(in_array($file_ext, $images))
          {
               $filename = 'images/'.$filecheck;
               $file_url = Storage::url($filename);
               $filecheck = $file_url;
          }
          elseif(in_array($extension, $videos))
          {
               $filename = 'videos/'.$filecheck;
               $file_url = Storage::url($filename);
               $filecheck = $file_url;
          }
          $file_array = array();
          $file_array['filename'] = $filecheck;
      }
 }
```

The purpose of the above is: to grab the filename that is returned from the database and map it to its appropriate filepath on the server. the contents of `var_dump($file_array)` are:

```
string(60) "/storage/images/DQP0GVcUA2dG8ZfqeVYLO68YodgYnJMOjJw2o2iC.png"
string(60) "/storage/images/vWUcHGX3VVKPT08JXh9mAqZ40pT0vfDJ78Yoqovz.png"
string(60) "/storage/images/bplX8bbwHzHKX9n6SvvQiYNhkWwKxi2bhsrQ94U2.png"
string(60) "/storage/images/8KAEovxQn3EgzHoZg1euSgNYTFupnLdKusJ4SIEP.png"
string(60) "/storage/images/uZ7fnDjlYfKU3pdSQ7wAq4siFryA6jSEitmRyPhp.png"
string(60) "/storage/images/4pslo6cC0I2E606DscWxiDD3sCBW7ZGaESQES4r0.png"
string(60) "/storage/images/xdVBMpV6PTLtX48M67kfWOqy59rsYMDZMuWbqDwl.png"
string(60) "/storage/images/hLtIGikARgARqmSqit4mqNXRFJthipH6O5vqxlbN.png"
```

This is where i get stuck. how do i now map this back to my array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in PHP the foreach works on a copy of that array so you need to set the data
on the original array i.e.:

```
foreach ($data as $index => $val) {
    foreach ($val['filename'] as $fileIndex => $filecheck ) {
        // convert file name

        $data[$index]['filename'][$fileIndex] = $filename;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code

```
    foreach ($originalArray as $subArray) {
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($subArray['filename'] as $filePath) {
        $filePath = //do your path thing here
        $subArray['filename'][$i] = $filePath;
        $i++;
    }
}
```